# Changing text on label in a custom prototype cell in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have google for two days now and can´t find a solution for my problem.
I have a tableView with prototype cells that have there own classes depends on what type of prototype that´s displaying.

I have one cell with a button, and when I press the button I want to change the text in a different cell.

I have tried to get the cell by tag, but the app crashes when I change the label text.
This is the code for finding and changing my cell.

```
LDCalcPriceTableViewCell *cell = (LDCalcPriceTableViewCell *)[tableView viewWithTag:666];
cell.priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ kr", [[note userInfo] valueForKey:@"message"]];
```

The error code I get is

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView changeLabelText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x924d230'
```

Comment: my answer might be wrong.. where do you call `changeLabelText` in your code ?

Comment: your answer was right. I had put the tag on contentview instead of the cell. Thanx again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set tag to Cell ContentView instead of the cell itself as shown by the error.

`[UITableViewCellContentView changeLabelText:]`

```
LDCalcPriceTableViewCell *cell = (LDCalcPriceTableViewCell *)[tableView viewWithTag:666];
```

even though you have casted to your custom Cell class.. it is not a `UITableViewCell`

you need to recheck and select cell and set its tag in the storyboard

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH......You have saved my day. I will set this to solved after 6 min :)

Answer (score 0):

NSInvalidArgumentException

Is Name of an exception that occurs when you pass an invalid argument to a method, such as a nil pointer where a non-nil object is required, check that.

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you that the method `changeLabelText` does not exist on the cell. Probably because the cell object you get is a plain `UITableViewCell` and not an `LDCalcPriceTableViewCell`. Casting does not help. Maybe you forgot to set the prototype cell as class `LDCalcPriceTableViewCell` in storyboard?